# reducer not getting executed in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

Hi iam very much new to this hadoop,iam trying to execute a simple chain of mapreduce job,but in my code reducer is not getting executed.here is the simple code what i have written

this is my mapper code

```
@Override
    public void map(LongWritable arg0, Text arg1,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> arg2, Reporter arg3)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("in first mapper");

    }
```

this is my simple reducer code

```
@Override
public void reduce(Text arg0, Iterator<IntWritable> arg1,
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> arg2, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("in reducer");

}
```

this is main class which runs the job

```
JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(jobrunner.class);
jobConf.setJobName("Chaining");

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/employee_data.txt"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf,new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/chain3.txt"));

JobConf conf1 = new JobConf(false);

ChainMapper.addMapper(jobConf,chainmap.class,LongWritable.class,Text.class,Text.class,IntWritable.class,true,conf1);

JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(false);

ChainReducer.setReducer(jobConf, chainreduce.class,Text.class,IntWritable.class,Text.class,IntWritable.class,true,conf2);

JobClient.runJob(jobConf);
```

Dont know where im going wrong.the sysout in reducer is not getting printed.any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probable reason:** you are not outputting anything from the mapper for the reducers to run at the first place. Try using  `outputCollector.collect(key, value);` from the mapper to write something for the reducers to actually run.

Comment: hi i have followed the way told by you,and my reducer is getting executed now i have to use the output of this reducer in another mapper.i have added an another mapper to the chain after the reducer but the reducer output is not coming to the next mapper,instead it is getting values from the file.any suggestions on this?

Comment: Since, you original question didn't have that, I request you to put up a new question stating what issues are you getting with a map-reduce-map chain along with the code you have tried. Please mark this question as resolved, if you think it solved your issue. Thanks!